# Getting 'fatal: No tags can describe' when running 'git describe' in an azure pipeline

Tags: git, powershell, azure-pipelines

I have a Powershell task that sets the app version using the current git tag. When the pipeline runs the Powershell task throws this error message:

```
fatal: No tags can describe 'b9cee9799b91f108547e1fcf0c8fcb1abef.....'.
Try --always, or create some tags.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

When I run the same command `git describe --abbrev=0` in a Powershell window on the same branch it works fine. I've tried removing `--abbrev=0` and I get the same error. I also tried adding an extra `--` but got an error of `fatal: Not a valid object name --abbrev=0`.

Here is the Powershell task YAML:

```
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Set Server Version'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        $releasever = git describe --abbrev=0
        $AppSettings = Get-Content $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish/api/appsettings.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
        $AppSettings.Version.Version = $releasever;
        $AppSettings.Version.Branch = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)";
        $AppSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish/api/appsettings.json    
      errorActionPreference: stop
      warningPreference: continue
      pwsh: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution. You have to set the fetchDepth in the Azure Pipeline YAML to 0.

For example:

```
- checkout: self
  clean: false
  fetchDepth: 0
```

Hope this helps those who've encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

September 2022 Azure Devops made an update to the default behaviour of checkouts. They went from not doing shallow fetches to a fetch depth of 1, and from syncing tags to not syncing tags. This applies to all pipelines **created** after the september 2022 update; previously created pipelines keep the old behaviour (for me, this lead to a lot of confusion!).

I solved the issue by adding

```
  - checkout: self
    fetchTags: true
    fetchDepth: 0
```

as the first build step.

Ref.:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#remarks
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml#do-not-sync-tags-when-fetching-a-git-repository

Comment: Azure's usage of git always baflles me in how many ways they can 'break the obvious', even if there were legitimate reasons for doing it.